# an array is taking all inputs in php and i want only the checked rows

Tags: php, html

i want to insert into database several items with its quantity
like name of food and its quantity using checkbox that handle the value of the food name. 
here is the code:

```
 <?php      ........
       if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            echo "<tr>
                    <td><input type='checkbox' value='$row[0]' name='food[]'></td>
                    <td>
                        $row[0]  
                        Qty: <input type='number' value='1' size='1' name='qty[]' id='qty'> 
                    </td>
                    <td align=right>$row[3]</td>
                </tr>";
        }
    }
 ?>

  <input type='submit' value='Add checked' class='btn btnSearch' name='add' id='btnadd'>

 </form>
```

action:

```
   <?php
        if(isset($_REQUEST['add']), $_REQUEST['food'])
        {
            $food = $_POST['food'];
            $qty = $_POST['qty'];

            $array = array_combine($food, $qty);

            foreach($array as $f => $q){
                $sql = "insert into entry (foodName,qty, meal_name, date, email) values ('$f', '$q' ,'$meal', '$date', '$email')";
                mysqli_query($cn, $sql);    
            }

            if(mysqli_affected_rows($cn) > 0)
                header("location:fitness.php");
            else
                echo $sql;
        }
   ?>
```

**the problem is .. array $qty is taking all inputs of the table not just the checked.**
and im getting the error:

```
Warning: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements in D:\ABC\First Stage\FitnessAddict\AddFood.php on line 93
```

Comment: Yes, that's how it should work, nothing in your code is telling it to disregard any of the qty inputs.  Associate the checkbox and number inputs together using the same key and remove all the keys from qty that don't exist in food.

Comment: What you want is a little complicated.  But basically you are sending two different count rows.  If you start with 30 rows...and you check 5, you get 5 food rows and 30 qty rows.  That's why it doesn't work.  You can't do it that way

Comment: @Devon can u write ur idea? i didnt get it

Comment: @Forbs so whats the solution :/

Comment: i was reading ur old comment. hehe ok i will try another thing

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you a better answer change this.

```
 <td><input type='checkbox' value='$row[0]' name='food[]'></td>
```

to

```
 <td><input type='hidden' value='$row[0]' name='food2[]'><input type='checkbox' value='$row[0]' name='food[]'></td>
```

then

in your code

```
foreach($_POST['food2'] as $key=>$val)
{
    if (in_array($val,$food,true))
        $array[$val] = $qty[$key];
}
```

That should work

So when you check a box in food, it compares the master list in food2 and says here's the matching key you can use for qty.

The issue is that the checkbox type only passes the checked values, and since you are using an array, you are losing the 'key' to reference qty.

Comment: i got a Warning: array_combine() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given

Comment: oh sorry, I'll fix that

Comment: can i use it like foreach($array as $f => $q) .. ?? cz it didnt work like this :/

Answer (score -1):

This will give you an idea..to save

```
<?php 
if(isset($_REQUEST['add']),$_REQUEST['food']) { 
    $food = $_POST['food']; 
    $qty = $_POST['qty'];
    $foodcount = count($qty);
    $i=0;]
    foreach($qty as $quantity){
        If(isset($food[$i]) && !empty($food[$i]))
        {
             $sql = "insert into entry (foodName,qty, meal_name, date, email) values ('$food[$i]', '$quantity' ,'$meal', '$date'
        }
    }
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($cn) > 0){
        header("location:fitness.php"); 
    }else echo $sql;
 } ?>
```

Comment: That won't work because you lose the $i in `food` when you combine a checkbox with an array